# Unable to convert query into Entity Framework form

Tags: sql, asp.net, entity-framework, linq, left-join

I have following query which I'm fail to implement, it has double left joins with two different tables

```
SELECT p.FirstName, p.LastName, u.UserName FROM 
 [APT2016_WEBDATA].[dbo].AspNetProfile p

 LEFT JOIN [APT2016_WEBDATA].[dbo].AspNetUsers u
 ON p.UserId = u.Id

 LEFT JOIN [APT2016_PFDATA].[dbo].[PF_Member] pf
 ON p.MemberId = pf.MemberUID

 WHERE pf.MemberUID IS NULL AND (p.FirstName IS NOT NULL OR p.LastName IS NOT NULL)
```

it returns `4300` results that is correct, but when I implemented it into entity framework it returns `29000+` results with following code

```
var result = (from p in AspNetProfiles

    join u in AspNetUsers on p.MemberId equals u.MemberUID 

    join m in PF_Member on p.MemberId equals m.MemberUID into msp
    from pfm in msp.DefaultIfEmpty()

    where pfm == null && (p.FirstName != null || p.LastName != null)
    //where msp.FirstOrDefault() == null

    select new UsersWithoutMemberViewModel
    {
        UserName = "",
        FirstName = p.FirstName,
        LastName = p.LastName
    }).ToList();
```

can someone please help me with fixing the issue

**Update:**

If I remove the `join` with `AspNetUsers` table it will return correct amount of data that is required but in that case I will loose the `UserName` that I will get from this `join`

Comment: What happens if you remove `join u in AspNetUsers on p.MemberId equals u.MemberUID`? The join fields seem to be different from SQL query.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, When I remove the `join` it will return correct amount of data that is required, but I also need `UserName` from `AspNetUsers`

Comment: I know, it was just for testing. Now try to join using the same fields as in the SQL query (`on p.UserId equals u.Id`)

Comment: Why are you using left join? Are there profiles without users? If you use the EF relations you should get the username by p.User.Username

Comment: Aside from the question, you should not query the AspNet tables directly as they are part of the Identity Framework.

Comment: @RuardvanElburg I have tables with the name `AspNetProfile` and `aspnet_Profile` so you are saying that I should use `aspnet_Profile` instead of `AspNetProfile` as they are auto generated by the Framework? this was already built project given to me and I'm opensource developer, first time exposed to `.NET`

Comment: I haven't used membership with profiles for a decade or so, but from what I remember you can access the member and profile using the Membership and Profile provider. Take a look here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/taab950e.aspx and here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2d449f1x.aspx.